# Visual Studio finds node_module in wrong folder

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I'm starting to create an ASP + Angular 2 project in Visual Studio. My node_modules folder is located in Web\node_modules but when running the application, Visual Studio is looking for it in Web\src\node_modules. How do I let it specify where to find node_modules?

For reference, this is the base project I'm doing:
[VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)

Answer (score 1):

node_modules always generated in the same folder containing your package.json file. So move your package.json file to the folder where you want the node_modules. After restoring the packages you will get the newly generated node_modules in the folder where you moved the package.json.

Comment: I did that but it seems like whenever I run my application, none of the .js files are deployed. An example is zone.js. What could be the problem?

Comment: Then there will be some errors while restoring the packages. Check it in the output window.